# NullPointerException on String constant

Tags: java

Looking at the logs of one of the production webapp (running in tomcat6 with oracle java 1.6), i found this exception :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at sso.manager.SimpleRegistrationManager.getCiviliteFromRCUValue(SimpleRegistrationManager.java:536)
```

Here is the `getCiviliteFromRCUValue` method :

```
private int getCiviliteFromRCUValue(final RechercheClient clientInfo)
{
  if (clientInfo == null || clientInfo.getCivilite() == null)
  {
    return 1;
  }
  String civilite = clientInfo.getCivilite().trim();
  if ("mme".equalsIgnoreCase(civilite))
  {
    return 2;
  }
  else if ("mlle".equalsIgnoreCase(civilite))
  {
    return 3;
  }
  else
  {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

The 536th line is `if ("mme".equalsIgnoreCase(civilite))`

How this exception is even possible ?

Here is the bytecode of the method (i didn't found the method with javap, i don't know why) :

```
// Method descriptor #366 (Lpass/sso/rcu/rechercheClient/RechercheClient;)I
  // Stack: 2, Locals: 3
  private int getCiviliteFromRCUValue(pass.sso.rcu.rechercheClient.RechercheClient clientInfo);
     0  aload_1 [clientInfo]
     1  ifnull 11
     4  aload_1 [clientInfo]
     5  invokevirtual pass.sso.rcu.rechercheClient.RechercheClient.getCivilite() : java.lang.String [142]
     8  ifnonnull 13
    11  iconst_1
    12  ireturn
    13  aload_1 [clientInfo]
    14  invokevirtual pass.sso.rcu.rechercheClient.RechercheClient.getCivilite() : java.lang.String [142]
    17  invokevirtual java.lang.String.trim() : java.lang.String [108]
    20  astore_2 [civilite]
    21  ldc <String "mme"> [184]
    23  aload_2 [civilite]
    24  invokevirtual java.lang.String.equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String) : boolean [128]
    27  ifeq 32
    30  iconst_2
    31  ireturn
    32  ldc <String "mlle"> [185]
    34  aload_2 [civilite]
    35  invokevirtual java.lang.String.equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String) : boolean [128]
    38  ifeq 43
    41  iconst_3
    42  ireturn
    43  iconst_1
    44  ireturn
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 531]
        [pc: 11, line: 533]
        [pc: 13, line: 535]
        [pc: 21, line: 536]
        [pc: 30, line: 538]
        [pc: 32, line: 540]
        [pc: 41, line: 542]
        [pc: 43, line: 546]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 45] local: this index: 0 type: sso.manager.SimpleRegistrationManager
        [pc: 0, pc: 45] local: clientInfo index: 1 type: pass.sso.rcu.rechercheClient.RechercheClient
        [pc: 21, pc: 45] local: civilite index: 2 type: java.lang.String
      Stack map table: number of frames 4
        [pc: 11, same]
        [pc: 13, same]
        [pc: 32, append: {java.lang.String}]
        [pc: 43, same]
```

Comment: can you assert that that particular log matches the state of this file? (in other words, has the file changed since ?) This should indeed not happen.

Comment: @Snaipe Yes. I checked out the file from the revision running currently in production.

Comment: Does something else in your application modifies the constant string table? This seems unlikely, but it could happen.

Comment: if `("mme".equalsIgnoreCase(civilite))` would ever throw `NPE`, I will go suicide. Perhaps the exception come from the old code

Comment: @Snaipe Not that i know of. The server was a bit more loaded than usual but that's the only strange error i found.

Comment: The issue is definitely odd. You could reverse the test with civilite.equalsIgnoreCase("mme"), since you happen to do a null check on clientInfo.getCivilite(), and trim() will not return null, but it's not even guaranteed to fix anything if something of this level is happenning. Does this issue happen often, or once every new moon ?

Comment: Also, could we get the bytecode disassembly of that particular function ? (filter from javap -c path/to/class/file)

Comment: Maybe you could post the code for the `getCivilite` method?

Comment: If the NPE comes from getCivilite().trim(), maybe refactor the .trim() to call it in setCivilite() (after a null-check of course). This will make the whole block exception-safe again.

Comment: I could advice to the question's author learn how to use debugging tools

Comment: @Andremoniy if the issue does not happen frequently, debugging tools are a bit out of the question. You don't get core dumps from exceptions.

Comment: @Snaipe why exceptions? If author has valid source code of library, so he is able to add exception-breackpoint and wait while this function will throw it.

Comment: @Andremoniy If the exception has happened *once* on a six month period, as this sometimes happen with production applications, you can't just wait with your debugger for that exception to happen.

Comment: @Andremoniy the exception happened 15 times on the same day but that's the first time we see it and only in production environment.
No new occurences since that day

Comment: @Snaipe that means mentioned source code above is not correct and from another version of library. The question doesn't matter a damn

Comment: Bytecode is fine, so I'd say the traceback must be off by 1 line indeed. You should call getCivilite() only once and null-check the result, as mentioned.

Comment: @Andremoniy Either you haven't encountered these kind of exceptions on a networked application, or you have forgotten the pain of tracking them (I'd go for the latter given your background). Not all exceptions are easily reproducible, especially when the state of the application depends on IO ressources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the problem is not the line you state in your question, but the previous line:

```
String civilite = clientInfo.getCivilite().trim();
```

This code assumes that `getCivilite()` always returns a non-`null` string. Just for the fun, try to refactor this to:

```
String civilite = clientInfo.getCivilite();
if (civilite != null) civilite = civilite.trim();
```

and see whether you still get the exception.

---

I noticed that you are doing a null check, but I'm not sure wether the same value is returned upon every call.

I'd try to change to code as follows:

```
if (clientInfo == null)
{
    return 1;
}

String civilite = clientInfo.getCivilite();
if (civilite == null)
{
    return 1;
}
civilite = civilite.trim();

...
```

We don't see the code for the `getCivilite` method. I've see code where values are retrieved from a database in a `get` method that returned `null` in case it could not connect to the database.

I there was something like that in your code, it could be the first call succeeds and the second call does not.

Just an example...

Comment: ... but there *is* a null check on clientInfo.getCivilite() above.

Comment: `clientInfo.getCivilite()` has been tested to be non null on the first line of the method.

Comment: there is a check for that - first line of the method.

Comment: Are you sure that `getCivilite` returns the same thing upon every call?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar there is only one thread manipulating the `clientInfo` object at a time so i think it's safe to say yes.

Comment: I edited my answer. Just for the heck of it you could try that and see what happens. It is more likely the `getCivilite` method returns different results than `"string".equalsIgnoreCase(null)` throwing an NPE...

Comment: "there is only one thread manipulating the `clientInfo` object at a time" - here you are reading, and the other thread may be modifying. So that's a valid assumption...

Answer (score 2):

Even if you say that threading is not an issue, I would rather do

```
private int getCiviliteFromRCUValue(final RechercheClient clientInfo)
{
  if (clientInfo == null) {
    return 1;
  }
  String civilite = clientInfo.getCivilite();
  if (civilite == null) {
    return 1;
  }
  String civiliteTrimmed = civilite.trim();
  if ("mme".equalsIgnoreCase(civiliteTrimmed))
  {
    return 2;
  }
  else if ("mlle".equalsIgnoreCase(civiliteTrimmed))
  {
    return 3;
  }
  else
  {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

This makes sure that the `null` check and the following use of the value match don't use multiple values.

And if you have several `equalsIgnoreCase` checks, it might be better to do `.toLower()` once and work with this string - if you are using a new enough Java version, you may even turn to `switch`:

```
  ...
  switch (civilite.trim().toLower()) {
      case "mme":
          return 2;
      case "mlle":
          return 3;
      default:
          return 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sadly, it must run on java 1.6 so no switch case on strings